# Ruby on Rails: Saving login status in session.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this admin_controller

```
  def login
    if request.post?
      if params[:full_name] == "adm" && params[:password] == "123"
        data = { :success => 'true', :msg => "Welcome, #{params[:full_name]}"}
        #redirect_to :action => :welcome
      else
        data = { :failure => 'true', :msg => "Username or Password wrong !"}
      end
      render :text => data.to_json, :layout => false
    end
  end

  def welcome    
  end
```

and i have `login.js`... everything is working!

How to build in `sessions`?

I dont understand the way i can. Please help me.

I have on page some links, and when I'm logged in and clicked on link, I get another page `(New post)`, excellent! But if i get back, `my application` wants me to enter login & password again. And if i enter my link url `(New post)` I get there with no problem, but it is wrong, there must be text something like : "`Log in first`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
session[:user_id] = id_of_user_that_just_signed_in
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  private  
    def current_user  
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
    end
end
```

Long answer: I wrote a tutorial on using Omniauth and in one part ("session store") you see session handling and writing the appropriate helpers: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16 (with full code on Github)